# While using IMPORTXML, why can I get IMG ALT but not IMG SRC?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use Google Sheets as a scraper to get product descriptions prices and images from a specific store. https://www.aliexpress.com/store/group/xiaomi-Aqara-Smart-home/2389096_516541380.html

I'm trying to retrieve the image URLs from this page but in the end, I'm not able to make it work.

```html
<div class="pic">
  <a class="pic-rind" href="//www.aliexpress.com/item/4000465413353.html?spm=2114.12010612.8148356.1.185c37e4M653t1" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.12010612.8148356.1">
    <img class="picCore lazy-load" alt="Aqara Opple Zigbee Smart Switch Light Switch Smart App Control Wireless Wall Switch Work With Mijia App Apple Homekit" src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hc5db6afe8de841f9a6ef4673dfb957c5W/Aqara-Opple-Zigbee-Smart-Switch-Light-Switch-Smart-App-Control-Wireless-Wall-Switch-Work-With-Mijia.jpg_200x200.jpg"
      style="visibility: visible;" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.12010612.8148356.i0.185c37e4M653t1"></a>
</div>
```

Using `//img[@class='picCore lazy-load']/@alt` works and correctly returns the **Alt text.**

However, when I change `@alt` to `@src`, (the information that I actually want), it returns `#N/A` (**Error** - Imported Content is Empty).

It is my understanding that I should be seeing `//ae01.alicdn.......jpg` (the actual image source).
Anything I'm missing with the Xpath?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: If i use `@*` I can actually see the expected `src` result after `alt`, but it gets thrown into the row below and I think this is what's breaking things. Not sure how to contain it into one row or something.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the url?

Comment: Sure, url added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page is loaded dynamically using javascript, and the sample html in your question is a result of that. Absent some trickery (you can search around for scripts to handle dynamically loaded pages), GS can't retrieve that data.

Fortunately, not ALL data is loaded like that. If you disable JS on that page, you will get most of the same data, including the `<img>` info; only this time - it looks like this:

```
<img class="picCore lazy-load" image-src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hc5db6afe8de841f9a6ef4673dfb957c5W
/Aqara-Opple-Zigbee-Smart-Switch-Light-Switch-Smart-App-Control-Wireless-Wall-Switch-Work-With-Mijia.jpg_200x200.jpg" alt="Aqara Opple Zigbee Smart Switch Light Switch Smart App Control Wireless Wall Switch 
Work With Mijia App Apple Homekit">
```

So the xpath expression you have to use is:

```
//img[@class='picCore lazy-load']/@image-src
```

That will output

```
//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Ha01fb531f16546368249b1efab8767341/Original-Aqara-Wireless-Flood-Water-Immersing-Smart-Sensor-IP67-Waterproof-Smart-Remote-Control-For-Mijia-Mi.jpg_200x200.jpg
//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hc5db6afe8de841f9a6ef4673dfb957c5W/Aqara-Opple-Zigbee-Smart-Switch-Light-Switch-Smart-App-Control-Wireless-Wall-Switch-Work-With-Mijia.jpg_200x200.jpg
//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H91d4b49011494602be752b446c45b530e/Aqara-Wall-Switch-D1-ZigBee-Smart-Zero-Line-Fire-Wire-Light-Remote-Control-Wireless-Key-Wall.jpg_200x200.jpg
//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H5078881ea11a443182bd3d3989ddf2a2r/Aqara-P3-Air-Conditioning-Companion-ZigBee-3-0-With-Temperature-Humidity-Sensor-Smart-Remote-Control-For.jpg_200x200.jpg
```

etc.

Comment: Amazing! This solved it! 
Crazy to think `alt` would just work but `src` would not... 
Thank you so much!